# Partial Swipe to Pop Breaks Interface Builder UI

Tags: ios, interface-builder, gesture, iboutlet

When I tap on a cell in a table view in my app, I present another view controller. This view controller is initialized from a nib with the initWithNibName:bundle: method, and I have a number of UIButtons with IBOutlets that I have configured through interface builder.

90% of the time, everything works great. I can present and dismiss the view controller as expected. Dismiss can happen with either a button on the navigation bar or with the swipe gesture.

The problem:

**If I start the swipe to dismiss gesture but then return my finger to the left side of the screen and allow the view controller to remain in place, all of my references to the outlets are broken.** The button's actions still send valid calls to my code, and their connected methods are being called, but any attempts to update the same UI elements fail.

Edit: I suspect the view is being partially deallocated or something. (Dealloc gets called when the swipe to pop gesture *starts*.

Comment: You need to show the code you're using for the swipe, and describe your controller hierarchy. Do you have a navigation controller or just a stand-alone navigation bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to be nothing to do with Interface Builder. My UI was supposed to update in response to a delegate callback method like this:

```
- (IBAction)didPressButton {
    manager.signInUser(self.user);
}

//Delegate Method
- (void)managerDidSignInWithSuccess {
    // Update UI
}
```

I was assigning the delegate in the init method, which was getting called and re-assigned when I partially swiped the VC away. Moving the assignment to the viewDidLoad did the trick and everything now works as expected.

```
-(id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        manager.delegate = self;
        //other init stuff
    }
}
```

should have been:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    manager.delegate = self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use Apple's template, the Master-Detail application, and build your project off of that, which would the most simple and easiest way to do it. If you do this method, your project will work very well and won't mess up.

Comment: This is a preexisting app. I can't start over. But thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Maybe try and import your other ViewController into it

Comment: I don't see how that will help with these outlets being set to nil?

Comment: When app crashes in the simulator, have you looked at the debugger?

Comment: Its not crashing... its just not responding to calls to update the UI

Comment: Nope. This is just something I'm observing